# Trying to find all matches in RegEx that say "I'm" but not at the end of a word

Tags: python, regex, discord.py

I'm creating a sort of "Dad Joke" bot in discord.py, and I'm using RegEx to find all the "triggers" to start the dad joke. Here's my code so far:

```
            string = message.content.lower()
            pattern = ' im | i\'m | i am '

            result = re.split(pattern, string, 1)

            if len(result) == 2:
                if "botpuns" in result[1]:
                    await message.channel.send(f"No {message.author.mention}, I'm Botpuns!!")
                else:
                    await message.channel.send(f"Hi {result[1]}, I'm Botpuns!!")

            await bot.process_commands(message)
            return
```

Right now it *works*, but not exactly how I'd like it to. It works whenever someone says things like "im hungry", but it also works when someone says something like "him", since that meets the criteria too. I don't want to make it check if there's nothing directly behind it because then it wouldn't work at the beginning of a message, but I'm wondering if there's a way to just check if it ISN'T at the end of a word. Thanks!!

Comment: That shouldn't meet the criteria, since you have spaces in the regexp.

Comment: Use `\b` to match word boundaries. `\bim\b`

Comment: You can assert the `regex` to start at the beginning of the line. `^im|i\'m|i am`

Comment: You can also use `string.startswith(('im', 'i\'m', 'i am'))`

Comment: @Barmar has the better solution here. Don't use `regex` unless you need to. `string.startswith()` is much better.

Comment: @PacketLoss Unless he also wants to match something like `Hello I'm hungry`

Comment: @Barmar, yes I want it to happen when someone either says `Hi I'm ___` or if they say `I'm hungry` but NOT if they say `him`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly from the comments, what you want is:

```py
import re
txt = "Hi i'm dad"

message = re.match(r'^(.*[\s])?(im|i am|i\'m)[\s](.*)$', txt, re.IGNORECASE)
print(message.groups()[-1])
# prints the last group, which is "dad"
```

`^(.*[\s])?(im|i am|i\'m)[\s](.*)$`

- `(.*[\s])?` - group 0(optional): any amount of characters and a single whitespace
- `(im|i am|i\'m)[\s]` - group 1: im, i am, or i'm are flagged here, followed by a single whitespace
- `(.*)` - group 2: any amount of characters.

Comment: IT WORKS!! THANK YOU!! but for some reason, even though it works, it gives me this error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'` but I'm not sure why

Comment: @badpuns That's because `message` returns None if the match didn't find anything. So you need a check to see if it returns None, and if it does, ignore it.

Comment: I did that, and now the error is gone. It works perfectly, thank you!! I marked your answer as the solution